# Remove author metadata from PDF annotations in preview?

Tags: pdf, preview

I need to provide comments on PDFs as part of the refereeing process for journal articles.  How can I remove my name from the annotations I've made using Mac Preview?  (they can be seen in Inspector: Annotations, but seem not to be editable)

Comment: What program are you using to make comments with? This question need a lot more detail in order to help you out. Please consider adding more details. Do you make the PDF yourself? How do you add the annotations? etc.

Comment: Preview is very limited in its capabilities. You really need to find another PDF editor for this and many other tasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the exact same problem. While you should anonymize yourself in the prefs, I don't fully trust that method, so:

1. Make a copy of the annotated PDF file
2. Drag and drop to open in a text editor like TextWrangler, or hex editor like  HexEdit
   (Don't worry about any binary-looking weird characters)
3. Search for your name and replace with the exact same number of Xs or I usually throw in a space among the Xs so it looks like a different name.
4. Save the file in place
5. Open in Preview and mouse over the annotations to see the anonymized version

Comment: Brilliant, this works - all I needed to know was that my name was being stored in plaintext.  Easy enough, thanks!

Comment: I did not even need to use a hex editor. Plain old Emacs sufficed, as I used the `replace-string` function in the raw view of the file.

Comment: This seems no longer to work.  I have just tried this on a PDF that has Preview comments that I need to anonymize.  There's now an `AnnotationDictionary` that seems to be a binary object, and I am unable to find the display name by searching in the file (with emacs or with grep).

Comment: That is disappointing Robert. Hope someone can find a workaround. Do you have a Hex Editor tool to try? I don't think grep would necessarily work.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman I was just able to change labels generated with Acrobat and with Preview version 10.1. I used `vi` to edit the file. The highlight text and notes showed up as plaintext, although the rest of the file was binary.  Maybe there are different flavors of PDF that are compatible and ones that are not. Mine said `PDF-1.3` at the top.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and indeed it no longer works (I tried with BBEdit). Could you update your answer and explain in a bit more detail the new method that worked for Acrobat/Preview comments?  Much appreciated ...

Answer (score 7):

In Preview, go to preferences

In the PDF tab

Select show or Not show the name in the Annotations !

[image]

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to remove my name from existing annotations?

Comment: apple seems to have worked hard to prevent this, all so that the nsa can track down anything in the end.

Comment: Bad approach. Works for added text but my username still appears in highlighted text. Don't rely on this!

Answer (score 4):

MetaClean is a powerful tool to view, remove and edit metadata of Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Visio), OpenOffice (word processors, spreadsheets and presentations) and PDF (versions 1.0 and higher) documents.

http://adarsus.com/en/metaclean.html

Microsoft Windows, Linux, Unix and Mac OS X Platforms

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second answer, this *does not necessarily work* if the .pdf was created using a different application, even if it is modified in Preview. *Always* use the Inspector in Preview to make sure the Author metadata is anonymized, and if not, change it as the first answer suggests using a text editor (TextEdit works fine).

For example, I often "print" web pages to .pdf in Safari, particularly news stories. If I open one of those in Preview and look using Inspector, my name shows up, even though I have "Add name to annotations" unchecked in Preview preferences as the second answer suggests. It stays there even if I annotate the document in Preview and save it.

I assume this is because it was added when I printed to .pdf from Safari. Safari preferences do not have a way to change user ID or anonymize saved documents in its preferences, as far as I can tell, so it reverts to System-level account information and adds my name from there when saving.

Again, *always* use the Inspector in Preview to make sure the Author metadata is anonymized before sending out a sensitive document.

(This should answer keflavich's question in response to Answer 2. In Preview [as opposed to common office applications or other groupware], your name is not associated with your annotations but with the document as a whole.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my complete method:

```bsh
export LC_CTYPE=C
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable file.pdf
sed -i "" "s/\/T \(UrCaseSensitiveUsername\)//g;" file.pdf
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf file.pdf                    # To correct errors
qpdf --replace-input --object-streams=generate --recompress-flate --compression-level=9 out.pdf # To recompress
```

If you don't like calling GhostScript, you may instead use

```
sed -i "" "s/UrCaseSensitiveUsername/_________________/g;" file.pdf
```

where `_________________` is the string composed of underscores having the same length as `UrCaseSensitiveUsername`.